# How to check if object is in json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, autocomplete

I am using google maps autocomplete and I am retrieving each object in a field like this:

```
$("#usp-custom-21").val(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("route"))[0].long_name);
$("#usp-custom-22").val(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("street_number"))[0].long_name);
$("#usp-custom-23").val(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("locality"))[0].long_name);
$("#usp-custom-8").attr("value", arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("country"))[0].long_name);
$("#usp-custom-25").val(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("postal_code"))[0].long_name);
```

But it does happen that sometimes we don't have some or all of those fields, and we get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'long_name' of undefined

I am trying to do a conditional by checking if these fields are there or not, and I tried both checking for an `undefined` or simply if it is there:

```
if(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("route"))[0] != "undefined") {
   $("#usp-custom-21").val(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("route"))[0].long_name);
}
if(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("street_number"))[0].long_name){
   $("#usp-custom-22").val(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("street_number"))[0].long_name);
}
```

But I still get:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'long_name' of undefined

And it refers to the `string long_name` inside the `if`

Full code:

```
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
      return;
    }
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
      map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
    }
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    currentLatitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
    currentLongitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
    var arrAddress = place.address_components;
    var Newlat = map.getCenter().lat();
    var NewLong = map.getCenter().lng();
    $("#usp-custom-19").val(parseInt(Newlat));
    $("#usp-custom-20").val(parseInt(NewLong));
    if(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("route"))[0] != "undefined") {
      $("#usp-custom-21").val(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("route"))[0].long_name);
    }
    if(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("street_number"))[0].long_name){
      $("#usp-custom-22").val(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("street_number"))[0].long_name);
    }
    if(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("locality"))[0].long_name) {
      $("#usp-custom-23").val(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("locality"))[0].long_name);
    }
    if(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("country"))[0].long_name) {
      $("#usp-custom-8").val(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("country"))[0].long_name);
    }
    if(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("postal_code"))[0].long_name) {
      $("#usp-custom-25").val(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("postal_code"))[0].long_name);
    }
    if(place.formatted_address) {
      $("#usp-custom-60").val(place.formatted_address);
    }
    $("#usp-custom-90").val(Newlat+","+NewLong);
    console.log(place.formatted_address);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
if(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("route"))[0] != undefined) {
   $("#usp-custom-21").val(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("route"))[0].long_name);
}
if(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("street_number"))[0] != undefined){
   $("#usp-custom-22").val(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("street_number"))[0].long_name);
}
```

Comment: I don't know why the downvote, yet it is working by checking undefined without quotes around. if anyone could tell me why this answer isn't right, I'd appreciate it

Comment: If you have solved this answer your question, please mark it as corrected

Comment: will do as soon as it let me

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
if(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("route"))[0].long_name != "undefined") {
   $("#usp-custom-21").val(arrAddress.filter(x => x.types.includes("route"))[0].long_name);
}
```

You may also want to check for NaN or null types. Use typeof to figure out a type when it's failing:

```
console.log(typeof x.types.includes("route"))[0])
```

or

```
console.log(typeof x.types.includes("route"))[0].long_name)
```

Comment: yes I have, only with undefined without quotes is working as per the other answer

Comment: Shame on me, missed these quotes

Comment: also console.log(typeof x.types.includes("route")[0]) is giving Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined

Comment: Did you put it inside the closure?